Cyclamen Has Flowered for 12 months
I have had a pink cyclamen for around 25 years. My friend eventually gave it to me as she's not good with pot plants. I used to water it for her, always from the bottom. My Mum, who was great with plants, used to say they like their feet wet. It came from Sainsbury's I think. Never been repotted. Has always had its dormant period, every summer. It flowered last autumn, and hasn't stopped. The leaves didn't die back. I have really never done anything differently other than water and feed occasionally. Why is this?

Congratulations!  We had a cyclamen that also flowered continuously for a long time.  The most likely explanation is a combination of right setting in terms of amount of sunlight, temperature and good watering practices combined with becoming pot bound where the roots of the plant have grown into all the soil in the pot.
To keep the plant flowering just maintain the same watering and light exposure.  You could fertilize lightly every other week with a flowering plant fertilizer  (the middle number for phosphorous is higher).
Sooner or later the plant will stop flowering and at that time stop fertilizing and repot to the next size up.

Thank you. I have always worried about repotting as it's doing so well. I'll try next summer.
